# Is there a better, less cumbersome way to extract text inline than <%= %>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, inline-code

Let's say I am working in a .aspx page (or View, for the MVC folk) and I have a block of inline code:

```
<p>Some HTML and content</p>

<% foreach (var x in foo) { %>
   <%= x.myProperty %>
<% } %>

<p>Moar HTMLz</p>
```

Is there a more efficient, less cumbersome way to extract text into the markup than this model? It seems like there are a lot of `<%`'s

**EDIT** I guess what I'm really asking is if there's any better way to get text on the page from a codeblock without leaving the code block, re-entering into a code block, and then reentering the enclosing codeblock.

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is strictly to have fewer <% %> sections, you can write it out the long way, but that's hardly an improvement:

```
<% foreach (var x in foo) {
       Response.Write(Html.Encode(x.MyProperty));
   } %>
```

If you just want to keep it out of the aspx page, you could move it to a control:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("properties", foo); %>
```

One advantage of this technique is that you could utilize a different view engine (say, NHaml) for the partial while still keeping the general structure of your aspx page (view) in tact.

Comment: yeah, but even if i pull it out and put it in a control, i still have to do the same thing. the question is, if i want to get simple text from a codeblock onto the page, is there another method other than `<%= %>`

Answer (score 2):

Create an extension method for enumerable collections:

```
public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> fn)
{
          foreach (T item in list)
        fn(item);
}
```

And then do:

```
foo.Each((i) => Response.Write(Html.Encode(x.MyProperty)));
```

Or, to make it even easer, use a custom view page (for MVC) or custom page class (for Web forms) that has a method that does this already for you:

```
public void WriteText(string coreText)
{
    Response.Write(Html.Encode(coreText));
}
```

To make it even easier.  Extension methods really help with that.

Comment: but does this detract from the fact that you still need 3 sets of `<%= %>`?

Comment: All you would need is:

<% foo.Each((i) => Response.Write(Html.Encode(x.MyProperty))); %>

One set of <% %> is all you would need then.  It get's all of that processing into one statement too, reducing the overall amount of code (especially if you do this operation a lot).

Other than aestetics, I'm not sure why you want to avoid several script blocks... it doesn't reduce performance...